# Send aggregation result on the main route, not the input messages

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, aggregator

I want to get the result of the aggregation as the main message of the route, not the original messages that came on the IN.
I also want to do this in one route.

I know I can use `.to("direct:one_result")` after the aggregation, but I have a strong limitation on doing this in one route, because I'm generating routes dynamically.

My `.to("mock:out")` will be replaced by a longer route definition.

```java
    from("direct:in").routeId("TEST_AGGREGATION_ROUTE")
    .log("<IN> ${body}")
    .aggregate(header("THE_ID"), (oldExchange, newExchange) -> {
        final List<Object> body;
        final Exchange outExchange;

        if (oldExchange == null) {
            outExchange = newExchange;
            body = new ArrayList<>();
            body.add(newExchange.getIn().getBody());
        } else {
            outExchange = oldExchange;
            body = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(List.class);
            body.add(newExchange.getIn().getBody());
        }

        outExchange.getIn().setBody(body);
        return outExchange;
              })
        .completionSize(4)
        .completionTimeout(30000)

        .log("<AGGREGATION> size = ${body.size}") // HERE I GET THE AGGREGATION RESULT
    .end()
    .log("<OUT> ${body}") // HERE I GET THE INPUT MESSAGES
    .to("mock:out")
    ;
```

The test output looks like:

```
TEST_AGGREGATION_ROUTE - <IN> BODY1
TEST_AGGREGATION_ROUTE - <OUT> BODY1

TEST_AGGREGATION_ROUTE - <IN> BODY2
TEST_AGGREGATION_ROUTE - <OUT> BODY2

TEST_AGGREGATION_ROUTE - <IN> BODY3
TEST_AGGREGATION_ROUTE - <OUT> BODY3

TEST_AGGREGATION_ROUTE - <IN> BODY4
TEST_AGGREGATION_ROUTE - <AGGREGATION> size = 4
TEST_AGGREGATION_ROUTE - <OUT> BODY4
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in your routing. You should not process the final results of the aggregation "outside the loop" but in a sub route. Do not put any statement after your end().

```
from("direct:in")
    ...
    .aggregate(header("THE_ID"), (oldExchange, newExchange) -> {...})
       .completionSize(4)
       .completionTimeout(30000)
       .to("direct:processAggregation")
     .end();

from("direct:processAggregation")
    .log("<AGGREGATION> size = ${body.size}") 
    .log("<OUT> ${body}");
```

Once the aggregation will have reached its completion size, the whole aggregate will be sent to the **very first** next "to(...)" endpoint. So what you want to do with every aggregate should me modelled in a **separate** route.

Comment: If the camel designers wanted to prevent people form adding other operations after the end of an aggregation, all they had to do is override the end() method in the AggregateDefinition class.

Also, as I said, "I know I can use .to("direct:one_result") after the aggregation, but I have a strong limitation on doing this in one route, because I'm generating routes dynamically."

Comment: Okay, but if you only want to replace .to("mock:out") by a longer (dynamically generated) route definition, why is this no more possible when this .to("mock:out") line is simply moved just BEFORE the .end() ?